# Падает приложение на андроид телефоне, Unity/

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Unity.
Сбилдил апку для Андроид телефона (Meizy m6 note 7.1 Android)
Устанавливаю на телефоне
Запускаю на телефоне.
Падает через 10 секунд.

Логи вот:

```
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.915 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   :  
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : (Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1758)
03-04 02:10:09.916 18468 18556 W Unity   : 
03-04 02:10:09.932 18468 18556 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xe5219970 in tid 18556 (UnityPreload)
03-04 02:10:09.933 10102 10102 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=18468 uid=10163 gid=10163 tid=18556
03-04 02:10:10.125 18566 18566 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-04 02:10:10.125 18566 18566 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'Meizu/meizu_M6Note/M6Note:7.1.2/N2G47H/m1721.Flyme_6.0.1511941566:user/release-keys'
03-04 02:10:10.126 18566 18566 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
03-04 02:10:10.126 18566 18566 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
03-04 02:10:10.126 18566 18566 F DEBUG   : pid: 18468, tid: 18556, name: UnityPreload  >>> ru.ninbous.game <<<
03-04 02:10:10.126 18566 18566 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xe5219970
03-04 02:10:10.126 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     r0 e52199c8  r1 00000400  r2 000000ff  r3 00000000
03-04 02:10:10.126 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     r4 cc6f3010  r5 00000004  r6 cc6f3010  r7 00000004
03-04 02:10:10.127 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     r8 00000144  r9 00000010  sl e5236ea4  fp 6b839cb4
03-04 02:10:10.127 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     ip d703de2c  sp e5219968  lr d61871ac  pc d6185ccc  cpsr 80010010
03-04 02:10:10.215 18566 18566 F DEBUG   : 
03-04 02:10:10.215 18566 18566 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
03-04 02:10:10.216 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00822ccc  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_Z34construct_block_size_descriptor_2diiP21block_size_descriptor+44)
03-04 02:10:10.216 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 008241a8  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_Z25get_block_size_descriptoriii+92)
03-04 02:10:10.216 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00827f50  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_Z20physical_to_symboliciii25physical_compressed_blockP25symbolic_compressed_block+80)
03-04 02:10:10.216 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 003fdbdc  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZL14DecompressASTCPKjiiiiPjii+292)
03-04 02:10:10.216 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 003fc524  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_Z29DecompressNativeTextureFormat13TextureFormatS_iiPKjiiPj+448)
03-04 02:10:10.216 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 003f0edc  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZNK9Texture2D11GetPixels32EiP11ColorRGBA32i+1264)
03-04 02:10:10.216 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 00d12ee4  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN13SplatDatabase18RecalculateBasemapEb+1892)
03-04 02:10:10.216 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 00d169e4  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN11TerrainData21AwakeFromLoadThreadedEv+20)
03-04 02:10:10.217 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 007fdbac  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN17PersistentManager23PostReadActivationQueueEiPK8TypeTreeb+144)
03-04 02:10:10.217 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 007fe798  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN17PersistentManager29ReadAndActivateObjectThreadedEiRK26SerializedObjectIdentifierP14SerializedFilebb+236)
03-04 02:10:10.217 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 007ff030  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN17PersistentManager26LoadFileCompletelyThreadedERKN4core12basic_stringIcNS0_20StringStorageDefaultIcEEEEPxPiibR12LoadProgress+904)
03-04 02:10:10.217 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 005ba9a0  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN18LoadSceneOperation7PerformEv+1476)
03-04 02:10:10.217 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 005bc748  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN14PreloadManager22ProcessSingleOperationEv+124)
03-04 02:10:10.217 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 005bc550  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN14PreloadManager3RunEv+104)
03-04 02:10:10.217 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 005bc3ec  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN14PreloadManager3RunEPv+44)
03-04 02:10:10.217 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #15 pc 0063c8b8  /data/app/ru.ninbous.game-1/lib/arm/libunity.so (_ZN6Thread16RunThreadWrapperEPv+84)
03-04 02:10:10.217 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #16 pc 00046fe3  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
03-04 02:10:10.217 18566 18566 F DEBUG   :     #17 pc 00019ced  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
03-04 02:10:10.289   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: runOnce 00
03-04 02:10:10.289   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: forkAndSpecialize 00  niceName:com.qualcomm.telephony
03-04 02:10:10.291   751   751 I Zygote  : ForkAndSpecializeCommon: Begin to fork a new process
03-04 02:10:10.305   751   751 I Zygote  : ForkAndSpecializeCommon: fork is finished, pid=18568 
03-04 02:10:10.305 18568 18568 I Zygote  : ForkAndSpecializeCommon: fork is finished, pid=0 
03-04 02:10:10.306 18568 18568 W Zygote  : mz_is_rooted false
03-04 02:10:10.308   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: forkAndSpecialize 01 pid:18568
03-04 02:10:10.308   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: parent closeQuietly before
03-04 02:10:10.308   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: handleParentProc before
03-04 02:10:10.308   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: handleParentProc 00 pid:18568
03-04 02:10:10.308   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: handleParentProc 01
03-04 02:10:10.308   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: handleParentProc 02
03-04 02:10:10.308   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: handleParentProc 05
03-04 02:10:10.308   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: handleParentProc 15 pid:18568
03-04 02:10:10.308 18568 18568 I Zygote  : ForkAndSpecializeCommon: Beginning of SetGids
03-04 02:10:10.309 18568 18568 I Zygote  : ForkAndSpecializeCommon: End of SetGids
03-04 02:10:10.309   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: handleParentProc 16 usingWrapper:false
03-04 02:10:10.309   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: handleParentProc 17
03-04 02:10:10.309   751   751 I zygoteRunOnce: handleParentProc end
03-04 02:10:10.309  1547  1607 I ActivityManager: Start proc 18568:com.qualcomm.telephony/1000 for service com.qualcomm.simcontacts/.SimContactsService
03-04 02:10:10.317 18568 18568 I zygoteRunOnce: forkAndSpecialize 01 pid:0
03-04 02:10:10.317 18568 18568 I zygoteRunOnce: child closeQuietly before
03-04 02:10:10.317 18568 18568 I zygoteRunOnce: handleChildProc before
03-04 02:10:10.336 18568 18568 I art     : IsDexFileNeededDisableVerify for /system/app/SimContacts/SimContacts.apk
03-04 02:10:10.336 18568 18568 I art     : Do disableVerify for /system/app/SimContacts/SimContacts.apk
03-04 02:10:10.342 18568 18568 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/SimContacts/lib/arm64
03-04 02:10:10.479  1547  2403 E ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo callingUid = 10065
03-04 02:10:10.489 18224 18243 W Settings: Setting android_id has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
03-04 02:10:10.492  1547  7528 E ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo callingUid = 10065
03-04 02:10:10.624   735 18028 I [GF_HAL][gf_hal_milan_an_series]: [gf_log_level] ret = 0, g_hal_log_level_flag = 0
03-04 02:10:10.624   735 18028 I [GF_HAL][gf_hal_common]: [gf_debug_info_flag] ret = 0, g_debug_info_flag = 0
03-04 02:10:10.655 18042 18250 I QQPimSecure: wup request: 1
03-04 02:10:10.666  1547  7428 E ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo callingUid = 1000
03-04 02:10:10.691  1547  2879 E ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo callingUid = 1000
03-04 02:10:10.693   586   586 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for service=netd_listener pid=795 uid=0 scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:netd_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
03-04 02:10:10.715   795 18585 W DnsProxyListener: Netd event listener is not available; skipping.
03-04 02:10:10.717 18042 18250 I DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
03-04 02:10:10.719 18042 18250 I HttpConnection: initConnection() openTimeMillis: 4
03-04 02:10:10.724   586   586 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for service=netd_listener pid=795 uid=0 scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:netd_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
03-04 02:10:10.990 18042 18250 I HttpConnection: sendRequest() connectTimeMillis: 269
03-04 02:10:11.066   753  1083 I AudioFlinger: BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4096) from active list on thread 0xe7c03f40
03-04 02:10:11.273 18042 18250 I ThreadPool: shrink core pool size: 0
03-04 02:10:11.419 17428 17634 I EventLogSendingHelper: Sending log events.
03-04 02:10:11.562 17428 17428 I MemoryTrimmer: Trimming objects from memory, since app is in the background.
03-04 02:10:11.739  1547 10899 I ActivityManager: Process com.meizu.net.search (pid 18334) has died
03-04 02:10:11.744  1547  1547 I OpenGLRenderer: SignalingRenderTask signal:0x7fa18552c0
03-04 02:10:11.744 17990 17990 I SafeApplication: onTrimMemory(15) foreground : false
03-04 02:10:11.744  1547  1547 I OpenGLRenderer: SignalingRenderTask signal:0x7fa18552c0
03-04 02:10:12.417  1547  7529 E ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo callingUid = 10051
03-04 02:10:12.429  1547  2931 E ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo callingUid = 10051
03-04 02:10:12.449 18421 18589 I DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
03-04 02:10:12.456   586   586 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for service=netd_listener pid=795 uid=0 scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:netd_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
03-04 02:10:12.481   795 18592 W DnsProxyListener: Netd event listener is not available; skipping.
03-04 02:10:12.485   586   586 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for service=netd_listener pid=795 uid=0 scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:netd_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
03-04 02:10:12.624   735 18028 I [GF_HAL][gf_hal_milan_an_series]: [gf_log_level] ret = 0, g_hal_log_level_flag = 0
03-04 02:10:12.624   735 18028 I [GF_HAL][gf_hal_common]: [gf_debug_info_flag] ret = 0, g_debug_info_flag = 0
03-04 02:10:12.939  1404  1473 W XTCC-5.1.0.23-d: [CS-RIL-LISTENER] timerCallback fired for ril update registering, re-register
03-04 02:10:12.940 10102 10102 E         : debuggerd: worker process 18566 timed out
03-04 02:10:12.943   883   883 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU2 [P:0] to CPU5 [P:1] (banned)
03-04 02:10:12.944   883   883 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ3 from CPU2 [P:0] to CPU6 [P:1] (banned)
03-04 02:10:12.944   883   883 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU0 [P:0] to CPU7 [P:1] (banned)
03-04 02:10:12.944   883   883 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ3 from CPU0 [P:0] to CPU4 [P:1] (banned)
03-04 02:10:12.945   883   883 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU3 [P:0] to CPU5 [P:1] (banned)
03-04 02:10:12.945   883   883 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ3 from CPU3 [P:0] to CPU6 [P:1] (banned)
03-04 02:10:12.945   883   883 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU1 [P:0] to CPU7 [P:1] (banned)
03-04 02:10:12.945   883   883 I MSM-irqbalance: Decided to move IRQ3 from CPU1 [P:0] to CPU4 [P:1] (banned)
03-04 02:10:12.948  1547  1996 E NativeCrashListener: Unable to read from debuggerd
03-04 02:10:12.948 10102 10102 E         : debuggerd: killing target 18468
03-04 02:10:12.950  1547  1637 I BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-04 02:10:13.022  1547  2899 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{6a350cc u0 ru.ninbous.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
03-04 02:10:13.023  1547  2899 W WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{5813e0b u0 SurfaceView - ru.ninbous.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity} from container Window{6a350cc u0 ru.ninbous.game/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}
03-04 02:10:13.024  1547  2984 I ActivityManager: Process ru.ninbous.game (pid 18468) has died
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По этому логу видно, что у вас на объектах висят скрипты, которых уже не существует.  "The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '') is missing!" это не ошибка, а Warning, он предупреждает, что на каких-то объектах остались ссылки на удалённые скрипты. К падению это может привести только если вы попытаетесь к этим скриптам обратиться и получите где-то "NullReference".

Ещё совет. Не знаю, каким образом вы дебажете, но там явно можно отфильтровать значения по тегу. Используйте тег "Unity" и из этой простыни исчезнут левые сообщения от самого телефона.

Comment: Локализовал ошибку, похоже дело в текстурах, но пока не пойму почему некоторые из них нормально работают, а другие приводят к вылетам

Comment: @Артур, вероятно, у них установлены разные материалы

Comment: Текстуры для террейна, и дело похоже не в самих текстурах, а в их количестве, если добавить 5 штук то все работает, как только добавляю 6 то вылетает, причем добавляя 5 текстуру фпс резко проседает даже если на террейне не красить ничего ей, и даже если она размером 2*2 пикселя фпс резко снижается с 20 до 13

Comment: @Артур, чем большее количество материалов вы используете тем больше "батчей" приходится делать при отрисовке сцены - это нагружает систему. Посмотрите эту статью, там описано, как можно выйти из положения, да и, в принципе, террейн очень накладное удовольствие в плане производительности особенно под мобилки. https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html

Comment: Спасибо, ваш совет очень помог, изучил вопрос, поднял количество кадров до 45 в секунду